# Распарсить html при помощи Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

У меня есть форма постов на форуме который мне надо распарсить:

```
  <tr> 
   <td class="icon_cell"><img src="/forum/images/message.gif" alt=""></td> 
   <td class="postslisttopic"> <a href="http://www.some_site.ru/forum/ссылка_которая_мне_нужна">Заголовок который мне нужен</a> &nbsp; <a class="newTopic" href="http://www.some_site.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotonew&amp;tid=1185343">[new]</a> </td> 
   <td class="altCol"> <a href="http://www.some_site.ru/forum/memberinfo.aspx?mid=226937"> Stat-mate </a> </td> 
   <td style="text-align:center">13</td> 
   <td style="text-align:center">1531</td> 
   <td style="text-align:center" class="altCol">9 май 17, 00:25</td> // и вот эта дата тоже
  </tr>
```

Мне нужно вытащить ссылку которая идет после `<td class="postslisttopic"> <a href=` и заголовок который после нее `Заголовок который мне нужен` (3яя строка)
И еще дату в предпоследней строке `9 май 17, 00:25`

И мне не очень понятно как решать с ключами вопрос, вот я пишу:

```
final Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.some_site.ru/forum").get();
```

И дальше я должен по идее как то вот указать что мне надо:

```
Elements tr = document.select("<td class=\"postslisttopic\">");
```

В общем что-то у меня тут все разваливается, помогите разобраться что тут должно быть? Чтобы мне распарсить это в класс с полями:

```
/**
 * Header of post.
 */
private final String header;  //Заголовок который мне нужен
/**
 * Author of post.
 */
private final String url; //"http://www.some_site.ru/forum/ссылка_которая_мне_нужна"
/**
 * Create date of post.
 */
private final Timestamp create; //9 май 17, 00:25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [Jsoup#select()](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) метод ты должен использавать CSS селекторы. В твоем случае это будет выглядит так:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp").get();
String url = document.select(".postslisttopic > a").get(0).attr("href");
String header = document.select(".postslisttopic > a").get(0).text();
String stringDate = document.select("td[style='text-align:center'].altCol").text();
```

Для парсинга даты смотри сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642720/proper-russian-month-string-translation-java

Comment: да но проблема в том что у меня тут 2 класса `altCol` и мне придется итерироваться через значение и проблема что я собираю не нужные данные тоже. Вот: `<td class="altCol"> <a href="http://www.some_site.ru/forum/memberinfo.aspx?mid=226937"> Stat-mate </a> </td> ` и дата которая мне нужна в таком же классе `<td style="text-align:center" class="altCol">9 май 17, 00:25</td>`

Comment: @Павел Посмотри, я обновил ответ