# Как распарсить html когда у него разные атрибуты имеют одинаковые названия классов?

Tags: java, jsoup

Вот такой html:

```
<tr> 
   <td class="icon_cell"><img src="/forum/images/message.gif" alt=""></td> 
   <td class="postslisttopic"> <a href="http://www.some_site.ru/forum/ссылка_которая_мне_нужна">Заголовок который мне нужен</a> &nbsp; <a class="newTopic" href="http://www.some_site.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotonew&amp;tid=1185343">[new]</a> </td> 
   <td class="altCol"> <a href="http://www.some_site.ru/forum/memberinfo.aspx?mid=226937"> Stat-mate </a> </td> 
   <td style="text-align:center">13</td> 
   <td style="text-align:center">1531</td> 
   <td style="text-align:center" class="altCol">9 май 17, 00:25</td> // и вот эта дата тоже
  </tr>
```

Проблема в том что класс содержащий дату имеет имя `class="altCol">9 май 17, 00:25</td>` и в то же время есть еще один класс у которого такое-же имя `<td class="altCol"> <a href=...` (4-я строка).

Когда я пишу:

```
final Elements dates = document.select(".altCol");
final String date = dates.get(и тут итерируюсь).text();
```

то у меня то я получаю то дату то автора а мне точно нужно знать что я получу. Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: тебе надо в итоге только даты спарсить или ты и то и то парсишь и нужно отличие поэтому?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский и то и то мне Stat-mate тоже нужен

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Распарсить html при помощи Jsoup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665025/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-jsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить наличие элементов внутри найденного. И если он не пустой — значит ссылка, в ином случае можно брать текст от предка:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
                + "<body><table><tr> \n" +
                "   <td class=\"icon_cell\"><img src=\"/forum/images/message.gif\" alt=\"\"></td> \n" +
                "   <td class=\"postslisttopic\"> <a href=\"http://www.some_site.ru/forum/ссылка_которая_мне_нужна\">Заголовок который мне нужен</a> &nbsp; <a class=\"newTopic\" href=\"http://www.some_site.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotonew&amp;tid=1185343\">[new]</a> </td> \n" +
                "   <td class=\"altCol\"> <a href=\"http://www.some_site.ru/forum/memberinfo.aspx?mid=226937\"> Stat-mate </a> </td> \n" +
                "   <td style=\"text-align:center\">13</td> \n" +
                "   <td style=\"text-align:center\">1531</td> \n" +
                "   <td style=\"text-align:center\" class=\"altCol\">9 май 17, 00:25</td> // и вот эта дата тоже\n" +
                "  </tr></table></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select(".altCol");

for (Element element : elements) {
    Elements innerElements = element.children();
    if (!innerElements.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("it is a link with href: " + innerElements.get(0).attributes());
    else
        System.out.println("it is just a text: " + element.text());
}
```

Comment: так он мне ссылку и вернет

Comment: @Павел кто "он"?

Comment: код elemeny.attr("href")

Comment: @Павел конечно не `attr`, а `hasAttr`. Поправил

Comment: `hasAttr` вернет `false`, так как `href` находится во внутреннем `a`, а не в самом `td`

Comment: У меня `hasAttr` всегда `false` получается. Вот так делаю:         `Elements elements = document.select(".altCol");

        for (Element e : elements) {
            if (e.hasAttr("href")) System.out.println(e.text());
        }`

Comment: @Павел `if (!e.hasAttr("href")) System.out.println(e.text());`  - ты отрицание (знак `!`) забыл........

Comment: Я конечно его попробовал, `false` всегда, `!e.hasAttr("href")` выбирается все `e.hasAttr("href")` не выбирается не чего.

Comment: @Павел да, я что-то подумал, что класс стоит на `td` и на самой ссылке. Написал другой вариант. см ответ

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский спасибо огромное действительно теперь работает!  А нельзя ли немного  комментариев добавить а то не как не пойму как оно работает. Вот эта строчка `Elements innerElements = element.children();` с вот этой `!innerElements.isEmpty()` почему здесь NPE не вылетает как так? И как вот это работает? `innerElements.get(0).attributes()`?

Comment: @Павел `почему здесь NPE не вылетает?` - потому что метод `children()` в любом случае возвращает коллекцию. Только либо пустую, либо заполненную. Вот если б он возвращал null или false, тогда можно было бы получить ошибку. А так, фактически, мы вызываем метод (isEmpty()) у коллекции............`И как вот это работает? innerElements.get(0).attributes()` - все тоже самое. innerElements - коллекция элементов, содержащихся в элементе с классом `altCol`..К элементу коллекции всегда можно обратиться по индексу. и посмотреть атрибуты элемента через `attributes()`

Comment: Все понял кроме `.get(0).attributes()` вот мы получили коллекцию и по нулевому индексу взяли элемент а `.attributes()` это мы получаем значение атрибута по этому индексу? Правильно?

Comment: @Павел `attributes()` — коллекция атрибутов (окончание метода даже намекает на это)) ) по данному индексу. ......для получения конкретного атрибута используется метод `.attr()` ...... то есть у той же ссылке по индексу 0, атрибут `href` можно будет получить так `innerElements.get(0).attr("href")`

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить дате, например, id и парсить по id.

Comment: не понял это как?

Comment: <td style="text-align:center" id="mydate" class="altCol"> например

<td id="something_else" class="altCol"> <a href="http:/

Comment: так сайт то не мой как я туда добавлю..?